# Checkmarx XSRF issue

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.0, csrf, checkmarx

Checkmarx is complaining about an XSRF issue in our web application. We are using ASP.NET web forms with framework 4.0 (not MVC)

Checkmarx said: *Method btnSubmit_Click at line 1760 of \ABC.aspx.vb gets a parameter from a user request URL from element text. This parameter value flows through the code and is eventually used to modify database contents. The application does not require renewed user authentication for the request. This may enable Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF).*

Any idea of how to prevent XSRF from ASP.NET Webform application?

We have tried a lot of solutions but none of them pass Checkmarx:
Here are some things we tried:
https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf
or

http://willseitz-code.blogspot.com/2013/06/cross-site-request-forgery-for-web-forms.html?m=1
or

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187740/two-solutions-for-csrf-on-owasp-for-asp-net-webforms

I think the solutions above should work and protect/prevent our web form from CSRF/XSRF risks, but why can Checkmarx not detect it? Is this a false positive?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without seeing the code.

Comment: take a look at 3 links provided above. That is what I have tried

Comment: You ask if this is a False Positive. We need to see your code to determine that.

Comment: do we have solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommend to check the CxQL queries from Checkmarx Portal (Settings/Scan Settings/Query Viewer) to understand how Checkmarx find a vulnerability, including what kind of protection that Checkmarx is able to detect.

For your case, check the logic in CSharp/Cx/CSharp_Medium_Threat/XSRF.

For Web Form Applications, the query CSharp/Cx/General/Find_XSRF_Sanitize is used to find if you have done any protection in your application.

As the comment of Find_XSRF_Sanitize said:

> For ASP Web Forms, the main solution to prevent XSRF attacks is to
> assign a unique token to the ViewStateUserKey property of the page.

Also

> AntiXsrfTokenKey

is also considered a protection.

If you use **ViewStateUserKey** or **AntiXsrfTokenKey**, all the http interactive requests that are defined in the same method as the **ViewStateUserKey** or **AntiXsrfTokenKey** will be considered as sanitized request, and will be removed for the potential tainted request list.

Note that in the CxDOM tree, **ViewStateUserKey** and the sanitized request have common ancestor, which is the method declaration.