# C# Additional String Validation For .text

Tags: c#, windows, ado.net, sqlcommand, checkmarx

I'm trying to figure out on the proper way for the additional string validation. I have an SQL query below which is compiled on c#, detected by Checkmarkx application that the **Row.Cells[2].Text** is not properly sanitized/validated.

```
string qry =
    "SELECT * from table_name " +
    "WHERE column_name = @variable" +

var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

if (!Regex.IsMatch(Row.Cells[2].Text, @"\w{1-35}"))
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
string name = Row.Cells[2].Text;   // here is the line at which Cherkmarx detected as un-sanitized/un-validated.

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", name);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Due to this detection, I have added the Regex.IsMatch functionalities but somehow it is still detected as un-validated. Is there any other way that I can actually sanitized/validated the variable Row.Cells[2].Text through C# so that checkmarx does not detect this as an issue? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 1) I don't see an INSERT query, 2) Parameters typically don't need to be "sanitized", what exactly does "checkmarx" look for? What does it consider "invalid"?  Is it assuming that you're doing string concatanation instead of using SQL Parameters?

Comment: What happens if you do not assign it to the "name" variable and instead just use this?

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", Row.Cells[2].Text);

Comment: @DStanley 1) I modified the question to remove the word "INSERT". 2) Since it is not properly "sanitized", checkmarx detected that this part could allow user to temper with the filter parameters.

Comment: @MelroyCoelho I previously did cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", Row.Cells[2].Text); but the .Text is detected by the checkmarx to not properly validated. I've added the Regex functionality above the line but it still detects as the same issue.

Comment: What if you move `string name = Row.Cells[2].Text;` before the `IsMatch()` and do `if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, @"\w{1-35}"))` instead?  Might checkmarx not assume that `Row.Cells[2].Text` cannot change?

Comment: You don't need to sanitize parameters, they are completely separate from code. Whatever tool you are using seems to be buggy, it should only trigger a warning if you use such values directly in the SQL text.

Comment: Checkmarkx appears to be a software security scanning tool (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmarx) like many others.  I've never seen a positive issue flagged as the result of using a SQL parameter in a query.  You say "checkmarx detected that this part could allow user to tamper with the filter parameters".  Well, yeah, that's the point of your code.  You code try some standard whitelist or blacklist filtering, but you shouldn't need tis to clean up a SQL parameter - that's the usual fix.

Comment: @dbc Just changed to move the line before the IsMatch(). Now it is detecting the string name = Row.Cells[2].Text as a Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) issue.

Comment: @Flydog57 what do you mean by the "whitelist or blacklist filtering"? do you have example on this?

Comment: @LiaLucindia - that seems strange.  Maybe it's a false positive?  [Checkmarx XSRF issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55029419/3744182) seems sort of similar but never got a proper answer.

Comment: Also, might you please [edit] your question to share the exact warning that checkmarx gives?

Comment: A _whitelist_ check says something like "only upper or lower case letters, the digits 0-9, hyphen, underscore or '$' are allowed" (you list things that are allowed), while a _blacklist_ check says something like "these characters are disallowed: '<', '>', '&' and both single and double quotes"

Comment: @LiaLucindia can you try using the AntiXSS library from Microsoft and HTML Encode the data? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8.1  FWIW, I think the evaluation of this by Checkmarx is throwing a false positive as stated above. This isn't the first instance I have seen after some searching on the internet where it's done this.

Comment: @MelroyCoelho just tried it. checkmarx now detect the variable as a potential of Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) now.

Comment: @LiaLucindia I honestly think now that CheckMarx will never give you what you want here because its giving a false positive on the vulnerability due to the way its seeing code.